# Finding parent element using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have the following typical Twitter Bootstrap / AngularJS form piece.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (loginForm.email.$invalid || !valid(loginForm.email, loginForm.password)) }">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
        Email
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm writing a test for CasperJS and I would like to test that the `has-error` class is applied to the parent of the element with id `email`. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
casper.exists(".has-error #email");
```

or

```
test.assertExists(".has-error #email");
```

should work.